# Qt4 custom window frames like in office 2007?

Tags: windows, qt, qt4, themes

is there a way to force Qt4 to draw window frame similar to office 2007/2010 ?
I want my application to look the same in all windows versions not just vista/7.

Maybe there is some extension to QMainWindow ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the titlebar and implement it yourself. It is part of the window manager. It is supplied depending on the OS you are running under (Windows, OSX, Linux...). It can be removed by setting the `WindowFlags` http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop

Answer (score 2):

if you are talking about the theme, then Office from 2007 onwards has the [Ribbon Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_%28computing%29)
[image: ribbon]

In Qt no ready solution is availble yet, as in the threads:

- http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/14376-Is-there-any-way-to-create-new-style-toolbar-like-in-MSO-2007-8
- [Does Qt support ribbon control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673666/does-qt-support-ribbon-control)

---

EDIT: a commercial READY solution: http://www.devmachines.com/products/qtitanribbon.html

Comment: Thanks, I was only looking for alternative window decoration.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.devmachines.com has a product called QtitanRibbon, that should serve your needs. Do keep in mind though, that you'll need to get a license from Microsoft to use the Ribbon interface. It is royalty free to obtain from Microsoft, but they will not give you a license should you want to create an application that competes with an Office Application.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But I am looking only for a different type of window decoration. AFAIK devmachines provides only ribbon that is displayed inside native window borders.

Comment: BTW I think that the only right that Microsoft has to this so called Ribbon is based on USA patents. So most Europeans can ignore it :)