# PyQT Remove the programs Title Bar?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

hi does anybody knows how to remove the programs title bar? (In PyQT or in Designer)
my goal is i need to replace it with my own title bar.

thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 29):

The title bar is managed by the window manager and not by the application.
Therefore you can not modify the title bar with the Qt Designer.

You can hide the title bar with `widget.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)` or `widget.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`.
These and other options are described in the [Qt documentation (Qt Namespace)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum).

The [Qt Window Flags Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html) makes them easier to understand.

This problem looks similar to yours: [Qt4 custom window frames like in office 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316197/)

See also: [How can I hide/delete the "?" help button on the "title bar" of a QT Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81627)

Comment: Please avoid links in answers... Three of them are broken.

Comment: Fixed the links. Avoiding links to documentations is not a good idea.

Comment: For PyQt5, "`widget.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`," works. The other one, however, doesn't.

Comment: Both `widget.setWindowFlags(widget.windowFlags() | ~QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` and `widget.setWindowFlags(widget.windowFlags() | ~QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)` work fine for me. Tested with Python 3.6.9 / PyQt 5.10.1 and Py 3.8.1 / PyQt 5.14.1 on Gnome.