# pyqt4 webpage hide window title bar

Tags: python, qt

I'm developing a GUI program in python which is essentially just a webpage within a `QT` dialog. I was wondering whether it was possible to remove the title bar because it looks horrible. So far, I have this:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
view = QtWebKit.QWebView()

class MyWebPage(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
def acceptNavigationRequest(self, frame, req, nav_type):
    if nav_type == QtWebKit.QWebPage.NavigationTypeFormSubmitted:
        text = "<br/>\n".join(["%s: %s" % pair for pair in req.url().queryItems()])
        view.setHtml(text)
        return False
    else:
        return super(MyWebPage, self).acceptNavigationRequest(frame, req, nav_type)
view.setPage(MyWebPage())

html = """
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
"""

view.setHtml(html)

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

I tried the instructions [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021502/pyqt-remove-the-programs-title-bar), but it's returning the error "`error: widget not definied`"

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the title bar with the Window flags:

```
view.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

If you want to keep a frame to resize your widget, for example, you should use:

```
view.setWindowFlags(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
```