# dotnetbar in Qt

Tags: qt

is there something like devcompenent dotnetbar in or for Qt ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing i see is [QTitanRibbon](http://www.devmachines.com/products/qtitanribbon.html), which i found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673666/does-qt-support-ribbon-control) stackoverflow question.