# Qt Ui Designer - creating window default frame and default buttons

Tags: c++, qt

when I create a window with the Ui Designer in QtCreator, most default templates give me a somewhat blank grey frame. There are options for adding more frames like that on the inside, but how do I add the default blue ribbon on the top with the window title, icon, minimize, maximize and close buttons? There is no option for that anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Qt support ribbon control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673666/does-qt-support-ribbon-control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you don't - that's up to the operating system. 
You can preview the window style with various skins in creator - select the skin under tools->options->designer->forms, check Print/Preview Configuration and there are various options for Style and device skins.
There are some options regarding window style under QMainWindow as well, for instance unifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac, but it is best to leave the outer window to the OS.

Comment: Also try Form->Preview in designer.

Comment: QWidget::setWindowFlags will also give some control over the title bar.